# InvalidROSPkgException when running roswtf: no manifest file in roscpp

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal, beginner-tutorials, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run **roswtf** as described at the end of the  [beginner tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Getting%20started%20with%20roswtf), but it complains about **roscpp** not having a manifest file:

```
WARNING(s) in /opt/ros/groovy/share/camera_info_manager/package.xml:
- The test dependency on "rostest" is redundant with: build_depend, run_depend
WARNING(s) in /opt/ros/groovy/share/diagnostic_analysis/package.xml:
- The test dependency on "rosbag" is redundant with: build_depend, run_depend
- The test dependency on "rostest" is redundant with: build_depend
- The test dependency on "diagnostic_msgs" is redundant with: build_depend, run_depend
Package: beginner_tutorials
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/roswtf", line 35, in <module>
    roswtf.roswtf_main()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roswtf/__init__.py", line 87, in roswtf_main
    _roswtf_main()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roswtf/__init__.py", line 174, in _roswtf_main
    roswtf.packages.wtf_check(ctx)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roswtf/packages.py", line 187, in wtf_check
    warning_rule(r, r[0](ctx), ctx)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roswtf/packages.py", line 68, in manifest_msg_srv_export
    msgs = set(_manifest_msg_srv_export(ctx, 'msg'))
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roswtf/packages.py", line 59, in _manifest_msg_srv_export
    m_file = roslib.manifest.manifest_file(pkg, True)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/manifest.py", line 118, in manifest_file
    return _manifest_file_by_dir(d, required=required, env=env)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/manifest.py", line 94, in _manifest_file_by_dir
    """%locals())
roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException: 
Package '/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp' is improperly configured: no manifest file is present.
```

What could be the cause of this?

My configuration: Ubuntu 12.10 32b, ROS Groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54045/invalidrospkgexception-when-running-roswtf:-no-manifest-file-in-roscpp/) by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Try executing roswtf command again after sometime in cd ~/catkin_ws. No errors and warnings this time in static checks summary. I also faced similar problem but when i re-ran it , it went fine. Hope works for you as well.

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on 2013-02-03**:
You're right, re-running it several times seems to get rid of the problem! I still don't understand why the problem occurred in the first place, however :D

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-02-03**:
Yeah, but if you go through http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/jj151528.aspx , and get to know the importance of manifest files, I guess while we run any command like roswtf above,  it was searching for manifest.xml file which is not present in

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-02-03**:
at the mentioned location, but package.xml is present. As the XML manifest can be any file in the archive as long as the relationship points to the XML manifest file and the XML manifest file conforms to the schema. So, dynamically establishing this relationship takes a while. Hence, rerunning

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-02-03**:
enables it to read through package.xml which is present. And it runs successfully.

**Comment by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on 2013-02-04**:
@ROS-freak Yeah, that sounds logical enough.